# React-native-linear-gradient doesn't work without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to get the linear gradient working using the library `react-native-linear-gradient`. Everything works fine when I run the code on Xcode, but it doesn't work anymore when I run the simulator using the command `react-native run-ios`, I get this red box in the middle of the page.

[image]

I guess that's because it's not able to load the library used to generate the gradient when I don't use Xcode.

If I run it from Xcode, I can't use the awesome auto-refresh and debugging features. Is there a workaround to get everything to work together?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something is a bit off with your setup. I can use `react-native-linear-gradient` from the command line, as well as able to use the Live Reload and Debug in Chrome when launching from XCode.